# Optional product in a Checkout Cart (/checkout/cart/)

Tags: php, magento

I have created a warranty as a product in magento which has 2 custom checkbox options. This product (warranty) does not have any specific page so I would like to display both the custom options of a warranty products as checkbox when selected one of the custom option the product (warranty) also should get added to the cart. I want to display this addon product (warranty) only when the cart amount is larger then $2000. Is there any way to achieve this function without having to create a module. I have attached a screenshot below to illustrate the custom option.

[image: Warranty option sample]

Comment: Might have more luck on http://magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

> without having to create a module.

No, there is not way to achieve this functionality without programming a custom module.

Comment: Hi Alan, Thanks a lot. I am very new to Magento and I have not created any Magento Module yet. Will it be daunting task to create a module for it or is there any module available for such functionality?